# Ruby 101: How Can I Save, Read, Write, then Save the Contents of an Array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, save, ruby-1.8

Thank you for taking the time to review and perhaps advise on my simple question. I'm seeking a solution for an exercise on which I'm working.

I'd like to know how to write the contents of this array:

```
@points = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

to this string:

```
saved_points1  = "SAVED_POINTS2 = [%s]" % [@points]
```

so that when saved_points1 is printed, it prints:

```
"SAVED_POINTS2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

Right now, I'm seeing this when printed:

```
"SAVED_POINTS2 = [1234]"
```

I have a feeling that perhaps this might be a ruby version issue. I'm on 1.8.7. Perhaps if I was on 1.9.x the array would print as expected? Or is there a different/better way to save, read, then print this operation?

In case it makes a difference, SAVED_POINTS2 lives within a module that I require at instantiation. I'm using the variables within that module to load/save the values for my new class (in which @points lives). I bet this isn't the right way to save state, but it's the only way I know how to do it at my current level of ruby comprehension. So, I'm not necessarily looking for advice on a better way to save state, because I want to make sure I understand how to properly read/write from these arrays first. But if you got advice you think I'd understand, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 6):

`Array#to_s` does indeed have different behaviour in ruby 1.8 and 1.9. There's universal way to get the string that you want. Array has a `join` method that concatenates all elements of the array with a separator. Your separator would be a string `', '`.

```
@points = [1, 2, 3, 4]

s = "SAVED_POINTS2 = [#{@points.join(', ')}]"

s # => "SAVED_POINTS2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I'll see about upgrading. Have to work it out with IT first...

Answer (score 2):

If you use the method `inspect`, it will work well in all ruby versions:

```
"SAVED_POINTS2 = %s" % @points.inspect
 # => "SAVED_POINTS2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]"
```